# Como colocar um numero exato de resultados de paginação cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp, paginação

Creio eu que por esse código eu consigo setar um número exato de resultados por página na minha paginação `public $paginate = array('limit' => 7,);`
Só que os resultados não seguem esse número e acabam vindo aleatórios.
Devo mexer em algum outro lugar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que é como você está fazendo.

Exemplos:

CakePHP 3:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{

    public $paginate = [
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => [
            'Articles.title' => 'asc'
        ]
    ];

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    }
}
```

CakePHP 2:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator');

    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'Post.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
}
```

Mas qualquer coisa procure pela documentação do CakePHP. Eles sempre explicam muito bem como que funciona os seus componentes:

Documentação:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html